# Change the page layout of a Word document to have two columns

Tags: c#, openxml

Basically I'm creating my main part onto my WordprocessingDocument:

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
```

I'm then adding a header and footer part to this document as well.

The only thing is that I need to set the main body part to have a two column page layout?

Does anyone know how to do this using c#? I've looked around a lot and most answers are a bit too old.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a document using Word, then open it using the [Microsoft Open XML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425).  This has an option to reflect (generate) C# code based on the structure of the document.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go for almost all problems à la "How do I do x when programmatically creating a document?"